# vscode jshint configuration

Tags: visual-studio-code, jslint

I want to exclude some diretory in my project and configure vscode jshint in `setting.json`

```
{
    "jslint.exclude": "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\tmp"
}
```

However a object is ecpected, so what is the key of object?

Answer (score 2):

`jslint.exclude` maps paths (which possibly contain globs) to `true` or `false` to indicate if the path should be excluded

```
"jslint.exclude": {
     "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\tmp": true,
     "**\\*.es6": true
}
```